# List of (un)deletion votes is incomplete

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I went through my (un)deletion votes on my profile page today and discovered that at least 5 are missing.

In the **deletion** tab, only 5 votes appear:

[image: screenshot]

That can't be true. I don't recall every deletion vote I cast, but I know that I ran out of deletion votes once, so there are at least 4 votes missing.

Likewise, the **undelete** tab shows only 5 votes:

[image: screenshot]

I cast all those votes on my own answers. However, I voted to undelete the question [How to destroy all hard drives contents as fast as possible?](https://superuser.com/q/435322). That vote is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "bug" with deletion votes is that once your vote successfully deleted a post, the post can't be shown anymore. Thus, it won't appear in your "deletion votes" list, even though you've cast the vote at some point.

The result is that for all users ≥ 10k that aren't moderators, they will have cast 0 deletion votes once all posts where they cast their vote have been deleted. And there's no way to look it up again.

While this sounds strange, it's just a result of the … let's call it "Stack Exchange policy" of not showing lists of deleted posts to non-moderators. In my opinion this policy is a little incoherent, because your flagging record shows deleted posts, but here I'm rambling again, so I'll just stop.

And for the undelete votes, it's the same thing again: You won't see your undeletion votes because the posts you're trying to undelete are still deleted.

Comment: So it's by design. Meh. *As for your missing undelete vote though, I guess that's a valid bug.* That should be the same issue, since the post didn't get undeleted.

Comment: You are so right. That is really annoying though – they should at least let you see those undelete votes.

Comment: I turned it into a feature request: [Don't hide (un)deletion votes cast on deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140328/dont-hide-undeletion-votes-cast-on-deleted-posts)

Comment: Glad you got to post it, this is long overdue. Thanks!